# Python pack / unpack converts to Objective C

Tags: python, objective-c, iphone, pack, unpack

I have one Python script and I wants to convert in objective C.

```
from struct import *
data = [10000,10000,10000,10]
d = [int(i) for i in data]
print d
list = unpack('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB',pack('>IIII', d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]))
print list
```

Output

```
[10000, 10000, 10000, 10]
(0, 0, 39, 16, 0, 0, 39, 16, 0, 0, 39, 16, 0, 0, 0, 10)
```

I have did first int array conversion in objective C, But stuck at pack and unpack

Objective C for first part

```
NSArray *timouts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10000"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10000"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10000"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10"],nil];

    NSMutableArray *ary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
    NSInteger coutner = 0;
    for (NSString *string in timouts)
    {
        int outVal;
        NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
        [scanner scanInt:&outVal];

        ary[coutner] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",outVal];
        coutner++;
    }
```

I have try to do so, But not much aware with Python scripting. Not got the way how `pack` and `unpack` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to say that you should try to learn Objective-C on a better level. It is not too hard (esp. coming from Python, because both languages are dynamically typed). However, I will give you some advises to your Q.

Let's have a closer view to your code:

A.

You have:

```
NSArray *timouts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10000"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10000"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10000"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10"],nil];
```

I really do not see any benefit from converting all numbers to strings. Simply store numbers:

```
NSArray *timeOuts = @[@10000, @10000, @10000, @10];
```

`@[]` means "array literal", `@x` means `NSNumber` instance object.

B.

You can print out the list itself simply with `NSLog()`:

```
NSLog( @"%@", timeOuts );
```

C.

You have to read instances of `NSNumber`, because you stored such instances:

```
NSMutableArray * bytes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
for (NSNumber *value in timeOuts) // Take out numbers
{
…
}
```

D.

Now to the hardest part: unpacking

Because you stored instances of `NSNumber` into the array, it is pretty easy to get the integer value:

```
NSMutableArray *bytes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
for (NSNumber *value in timeOuts) // Take out numbers
{
   int intValue = [value intValue];
   …
}
```

E.

You can "pack them" into a string with `-stringWithFormat:`. However, if I understand the log in your Q correct, you want to print out the single bytes of a value, not the whole value.

```
NSMutableArray *bytes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
for (NSNumber *value in timeOuts) // Take out numbers
{
   int intValue = [value intValue];
   for( int x = 0; x < 4; x++ )
   {
     int byte = intValue & 0xFF000000; // Mask out bit 0-23
     [bytes addObject:@(byte)];  // Store byte
     intValue <<= 8;             // Shift up bit 0-23 to 8-31 for the next iteration

   }
}
NSLog( @"%@", bytes );
```

z.

So we end up with this:

```
NSArray *timeOuts = @[@10000, @10000, @10000, @10];
NSLog( @"%@", timeOuts );

NSMutableArray *bytes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
for (NSNumber *value in timeOuts) // Take out numbers
{
   int intValue = [value intValue];
   for( int x = 0; x < 4; x++ )
   {
     int byte = intValue & 0xFF; // Mask out bit 8-31
     [bytes addObject:@(byte)];  // Store byte
     intValue >>= 8;             // Shift down bit 8-31 to 0-23 for the next iteration

   }
}
NSLog( @"%@", bytes );
```

If you really need to store the values as strings, let me know. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Almost done. I see output byte array has reverse 4 bytes. 16,39,0,0,16,39,0,0,16,39,0,0,10,0,0,0
Its not exact as python output.

Comment: Few changes in objective c loop and done. Editing Z answer block. 
    NSMutableArray *bytes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
    for (NSNumber *value in timeOuts)
    {
        NSMutableArray *newBytes = [NSMutableArray array];
        int intValue = [value intValue];
        for( int x = 0; x < 4; x++ )
        {
            int byte = intValue & 0xFF;
            [newBytes addObject:@(byte)];
            intValue >>= 8;
        }
        NSArray *reversed = [[newBytes reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
        [bytes addObjectsFromArray:reversed];
    }

Comment: Well, reading code in comments is close to impossible. But I edited my answer. It is easier than you might think.